# Connecting via VPN to a cloud VPS

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

**Problem Statement:** How do I connect to my Digital Ocean Cloud VPS via SSH over a secured network such as a VPN / Tunneling?

**Detailed Context:**
1. **My Server:** a CentOS 7 Droplet with a public IP on eth0 & private IP on eth1
2. **SSH Clients (*via SSH keys*):** MobaXterm on Windows 7 OR VirtualBox CentOS 7 VM

**Situation?**
My home computer's public WAN IP address changes every time I restart my router or based on their DHCP Policy (*whichever comes 1st*)

How do I setup a mechanism wherein I connect to an IP or FQDN that's permanently white-listed in my VPS's Firewall (*something similar to AWS Security groups*) before subsequently starting a SSH session without setting up a 2nd Linux VPS just for VPN purposes? The below flow should make it fairly clearer:

```
SSH Clients from my PC(_Random Src IPs_) --> VPN / Tunnel (_1+ IPs white-listed in VPS Firewall_) -->[SSH] --> VPS
```

**Options NOT Possible**

1. VPN Server on the same VPS (*becomes a single point of failure*)
2. A 2nd Linux VPS setup like a [Jumpbox | Bastion Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server) since the 1st VPS is not a production grade server plus maintaining 2 VPS isn't economically feasible for me.

**Options Possible**

1. A reliable VPN Service that's free for personal use.
2. SSH Tunneling or any other alternative.

Please let me know if anymore context is needed & guide me the ideal way to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe you could add why you want to do that? If you want to improve security, using ssh-keys is sufficient in most cases. If you need more protection, you could set up 2FA authentication…

Comment: I'm already using SSH Keys but the reason I want to do this is to reduce effort on white-listing multiple IPs as well as not expose my SSH port to the world. In my current scenario, I have to keep adding newer subnets to my firewall since my ISP has a huge pool of IPs.      
    

could you please suggest me anything using the above context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [tunnel your SSH connection through Tor](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en).

To do that, configure the SSH server to listen only on localhost and put something like this into `/etc/tor/torrc`:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
HiddenServiceVersion 3 # If you're using tor 0.3.2 or above.
```

Then restart Tor. Your onion hostname will be generated and can be found in `/var/lib/tor/ssh_hidden_service/hostname`.

[Configure your SSH client to use Tor](https://askubuntu.com/a/111944) by putting something like this into `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host mydomain
    HostName mydomain.com
    CheckHostIP no
    ProxyCommand connect-proxy -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve %h localhost:9050) %p
```

You will need to install the package connect-proxy. Or you could use [netcat as ProxyCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616021/5965450).

Comment: Didn't know Tor was usable as a SSH proxy. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337082/install-tor-on-a-centos-7-server) instead of compiling so I'll give your idea a spin. 

Since Tor routes packets via their vastly dynamic [network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)), does this mean I'll have to keep my SSH port (_either the standard 22 or alternatively 8888 in my case_) open from all internet traffic? 

If yes, I'd like to avoid it since I could potentially be targeted via brute-force attacks thus needing to setup a rate-limiter like fail2ban

Comment: Your SSH server only has to listen on localhost. The HiddenServicePort is open to the Tor network but is only reachable through you onion address, a 56-character long random string. If you keep it secret, it is highly unlikely someone is gonna find it.